# not able to configure cofoja on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, design-by-contract

Eclipse is up to date, cofoja too, and so are java jre/jdk.
ASM should be included in cofoja, but I downloaded the 3.3 just in case.

I followed all the procedures I could find in internet, but the first error eclipse is giving never changed from the first step: "Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatements".

The code is very basic:

```
import java.io.whatever;
import java.net.whatever;
import com.google.java.contract.Requires;

public class ManageSocketServerExplicit{
    [...]

    public ManageSocketServerExplicit(String p_ipAddress, int p_port){
        @Requires("p_port >= 0")
        this(p_ipAddress,p_port,10,1000);
        [...]
    }
}
```

The error is obviously at the end of the Require.

Configuration
There are several projects in the directory. Let's say that I want to use cofoja just on one of them.
The base directory is C:\svn_java\Progetti_NET, in which there is the project I want to use cofoja on, which is 'Malu'. Into it there are multiple source directories, not just a generic 'src', but the main is called 'Code', and it's the principal.
So the paths are (tried them with both slashes, nothing changes):
classoutput  C:\svn_java\Progetti_NET\Malu\bin
classpath  C:\svn_java\cofoja-1.1-r146.jar
sourcepath  C:\svn_java\Progetti_NET\Malu\Code
Eclipse understands the namespace of cofoja, by the way: I can see the objects listed if I auto-complete them.

So 'Annotation Processing' is all set, and 'Factory Path' again contains "c:\svn_java\cofoja-1.1-r146.jar". The workspace automatically updates when there are changes, and both asmn and cofoja are in the libraries of the 'Java Build Path'.

I tried to add also the -vm command in eclipse.ini to use the jdk (C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin), but again nothing changed.

Since the configuration is pretty simple it shouldn't be so hard to fix it, but I don't know how.

Comment: honestly, I've fiddling around half an hour searching wtf this thing gave as a "formatting error"... a setting like "I don't care about errors in the post BECAUSE THEY ARE NOT ERRORS" would be useful! expecially when i'm in haste!

Answer (score 2):

i used Cofoja with eclipse and i used this [link](http://fsteeg.com/2011/02/07/setting-up-contracts-for-java-in-eclipse/) to configure it.
However it has a missing factory path. You need to state the sourcepath too as shown in my image.
If you run it using eclipse, you have to set the run configurations of the file and add the following VM arguements
-javaagent:*PATH TO JAR*/cofoja.jar

And @Requires and @Ensures are method-level contracts.
You cant write it within the method. Instead you need to write it as follows

public class ManageSocketServerExplicit{

> ```
> [...]
> @Requires("p_port >= 0") // CONTRACT
> public ManageSocketServerExplicit(String p_ipAddress, int p_port){
>
>     this(p_ipAddress,p_port,10,1000);
>     [...]
> } }
> ```

Hope it helps :D

[image: Factory Path]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already understood what I was doing wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understood what was wrong: after adding the source code of cofoja to the project I understood I placed the @Requires in the wrong place... The annotation @Ensures gave me this error, but I forgot about it.
:(

Answer (score 0):

a very well realized tutorial: http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/236700/Spring2013/ho/WCFiles/Contracts%20for%20Java.pdf